# Comments section in form fields arrangement

Tags: forms, comments

Just wondering if there is a best practice for when a comments section ( a larger text field) is to be included amidst a bunch of regular size text fields in case of a non-modal situation. An example is shown here. any will be great.

[image]

Comment: Why not have regular size and once typing beyond the limit, increase the height accordingly? One more thing, Z-Scanning patterns in forms are tedious for users to fill and reduce the rate of form completion.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the comment field at the end without putting it bigger, but with a help text that tells you how many characters you can enter. As they all say too, you should align the form vertically according to the Z-scan design pattern and with respect to the date it is more advisable to handle it in a single box and not in 3.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about best practice, but I'd expect it to run vertically instead of being spread out all over the page like that.

Answer (score 0):

A "comments/further information" section would probably be expected to be at the end of the form, so depending on width of the window, you could have it as full-width.

Based on the fields there, you may want to center them more and make the form more vertical. Then with the smaller width, a full-width textarea wouldn't seem as out of place. If it's still too wide then, you could instead make it more high than wide, and if it's tall enough, place 2 fields to the other side of it.